# How to pass variables from one module to another?

Tags: perl

I would like to pass a variable from a module to another. I googled how to do this, and quickly found the `Exporter` documentation, which told me NOT to ever export variable names.

One of my modules reads a path from configuration file; I would prefer to pass that path to another module rather than have that module read it again...is this allowed?

Comment: You would usually pass this as parameters to functions or methods.

Comment: In other words, instead of making a new module I should just make a subroutine?

Comment: Indeed jm666. @Biology2795733, a module is "just" (mostly) a collection of subroutines, so you usually call those subs and pass them any arguments you need. If you got OO, then you can have a constructor (usually `new`) to which you can pass arguments which you save in the object for later use by the other methods (subroutines) of the object.

Comment: So, as a rule of thumb, if sections of code are sharing variables, it's best that they be contained within the same package?

Comment: What if you want to run subroutines in parallel?

Comment: Parallelism has nothing to do with the use of modules. To run things in parallel use `fork` (or `threads`).

Comment: @Biology2795733, yes, ideally they should be in the same package, and you can then have variables that are local to that package. Or if you go the OO route, the "variables" could be local to an object instance. If you go multi-threaded, then the latter is definitely the best option, but we're getting into very advanced topics here.

Comment: Doesn't a package like `slurp` import a variable from another package?

Comment: I currently have 3 scripts that are each about 800 lines. I have been using the first to call the 2nd and 3rd via `system "start cmd.exe perl script2 $arg1 $arg2 $arg3...$arg8"`. I have a feeling that this is suboptimal. You would suggest then that I copy the entire 2nd script into the first as a subroutine `script2` and call `script2($arg1,...,$arg8)`?

Comment: Or put `script2` into a separate module and export it to script 1, where it can be called as I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

You can share global variables between modules. I use it mostly to share debug flag across all the module's submodules, without having to use the var full name:

```
# in main module:
our $DEBUG;
# in sub module:
our $DEBUG;
*DEBUG = \$MainModule::DEBUG;
```

Then you can just check $DEBUG in the submodule too. if someone changes it in for one of the variables, everyone sees the new value automatically.

That said, it is good for debug flags. In your case, I'd recommend making a singleton configuration module, so you will be able to use:

```
my $path = App::Config->get_path();
# or maybe:
my $path = $app->config->get_path();
```

from everywhere in the program.

Comment: I thought about doing this, and I like it because then if I change the configuration file it will change it for every module (previously, I had some paths hardcoded into each module separately). For this, however, I have to call this configuration module from every module. Why is this better than just passing some variables between modules?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean in "passing some variables between modules". Module isn't a function that you pass parameter to it. 
And using a singleton is preferred because you keep all your globals in one place, and can manage them there.